# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].sAcctDesc"

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit4, querydsl

I am trying to write test case for Account controller class. Account controller is depends on Account service class so I am using `mockito`. In Account Service I am using `Querydsl` for creating dynamic query for implementing search filter.

I tried to write test case like below. In that test class I am able to receive query result in array format. But I am getting empty body and because of that getting this error  `java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].sAcctDesc"`

Can any one tell me why I am getting empty body?

**AccountController**

```
    @GetMapping("/findAccountData")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(@RequestParam(value="sClientAcctId",required=false) String sClientAcctId,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sAcctDesc",required=false) String sAcctDesc,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sInvestigatorName",required=false)String sInvestigatorName,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sClientDeptId",required=false) String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {
            return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc,sInvestigatorName,sClientDeptId));
        }
```

**TestAccountControllerGrid**

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    public class TestAccountControllerGrid {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        private AccountService accountService;

        @InjectMocks
        private AccountController accountController;

        @Autowired
        EntityManager em;

        @Value("${InstituteIdentifier}")
        private String instituteIdentifier;

        @Test
        @Transactional
        public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {

            String sClientAcctId ="5400343";
            String sAcctDesc =" ASTRALIS LTD";
            String sInvestigatorName ="Krueger, James G.";
            String sClientDeptId ="112610";


            Department departmentObject = new Department();     
            departmentObject.setsClientDeptId("112610");
            departmentObject.setsDeptName("Konarska Laboratory");

            Investigator investigatorObject= new Investigator();    
            investigatorObject.setsInvestigatorName("Krueger, James G.");

            Account accountObject = new Account();      
            accountObject.setsAcctDesc(" ASTRALIS LTD");
            accountObject.setsClientAcctId("5400343");
            accountObject.setsLocation("A");
            accountObject.setDepartment(departmentObject);
            accountObject.setInvestigator(investigatorObject);

            em.merge(accountObject);

            QAccount account = QAccount.account;

            JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
            List<Tuple> result = query.select(account.sAcctDesc, account.sClientAcctId,account.sLocation)
                                      .from(account).fetch();   

            System.out.println("Query Result = "+ result);

            Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
            .thenReturn(result).toString();


            mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/"+instituteIdentifier+"/admin/account/findAccountData")
                    .param("sClientAcctId", "5400343")
                    .param("sAcctDesc", " ASTRALIS LTD")
                    .param("sInvestigatorName", "Krueger, James G.")
                    .param("sClientDeptId", "112610")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    )
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())   
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sClientAcctId", is("5400343")))               
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sClientAcctId", is("5400343")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sLocation", is("A")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].department.sDeptName", is("Konarska Laboratory")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].investigator.sInvestigatorName", is("Krueger, James G.")));

            Mockito.verify(accountService).populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId);
        }
    }
```

**Console**

Here I am able to receive query result still that body is empty. Can any one tell me why that body is []  ?

```
    Query Result = [[ ASTRALIS LTD, 5400343, A]]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /spacestudy/rockefeller/admin/account/findAccountData
       Parameters = {sClientAcctId=[5400343], sAcctDesc=[ ASTRALIS LTD], sInvestigatorName=[Krueger, James G.], sClientDeptId=[112610]}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is empty here:

```
System.out.println("result "+result); // getting empty []
```

On this next line you specify for Mockito that when the AccountService method populateGridViews(...) are called you wish to return the empty result array:

```
Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
    .thenReturn(result);
```

Then the mockMvc.perform(...) method calls your endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/findAccountData")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(...){...}
```

This method calls the AccountService method populateGridViews(...) :

```
accService.populateGridViews(...)
```

Mockito will now skip the real method call and instantly return the empty result array from before.

Comment: I don't want to use real method I have to use mockito .one more thing  I don't want to return empty result but I am getting there empty []. I am excepting some Query result  .....how I can do that?

Comment: Do you want to use the AccountService method: populateGridViews (...) ?

Comment: If you wish to use the method populateGridViews (...)  you can't mock it. If you wish to mock the method then this code:
 
JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
List<Tuple> result = query.from(account).fetch();

Should return a list with Tuples containing the values.

Comment: I updated my test class. In that I am able to return  list of result  but still I am getting body []